# Creating IPSW Downloader with JSON and VB.Net

Tags: ios, iphone, json, vb.net

I'm trying to create an IPSW Downloader written in VB.Net, and I managed to get this link (https://api.ipsw.me/v2.1/firmwares.json) that always keeps the latest links available for IPSW updated . This link is written in JSON.

The application should be structured like this:

- 2 ComboBox (one to select the device and the other to select the version of iOS)
- 1 Button to download the IPSW (the link is in the JSON)
- Some Label, where there are written to the firmware information (file size, MD5m SHA1, etc., That information contained within the file JSON)

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance to everyone who will respond! :P

Comment: What specific problem are you having with creating this application? It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Help with *what* exactly?  Parsing the json?  using a combobox? You need to make some effort and when you get stuck on a *specific* programming problem, post a specific question.  This is too vague and too broad.

Comment: Please read [Ask] *carefully*